# how to correctly remove subviews from UITableViewCell.contentview when cell is re-used

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

- I add subviews to each contentView of each cell
- subviews are different for each cell
- I identify a cell by setting its tag
- Since cells CAN BE re-used, I first remove all its subviews before returning the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

> [[cell.contentView subviews]
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

My problem is:

- cell is not rendered correctly when performing above code. The **detailText** is cutoff
- If dont do the above statement, detailText is fine but **wrong** **subviews** are there.

So, how to correctly remove subviews from UITableViewCell.contentview when cell is re-used??

Is there a completionHandlet hook?

*Should I run above code in background queue and render the cell in main queue? Is that the correct way?*

Comment: One approach is to use a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and implement the `prepareForReuse` method.

Comment: `detailText` is probably cut off because you set its `frame` incorrectly.

Comment: @AaronBrager then why is detailText fine when I dont use the mentioned code

Comment: Show the code you're using and I might be able to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution, but you can tag your custom subviews, and then:
  for view in subviews...
  If view.tag == myTag // remove from superview

A better solution would be to make a few table view cell subclasses, reusing your custom subviews.

Comment: I already tried that..hence I used the word "correctly" while asking the question....thank you for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a bunch of code in swift to simulate your problem, things are working ok (taking in consideration the small complexity of the subviews):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  example
//
//  Created by Tiago Maia Lopes on 2/17/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 -. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

tableView.rowHeight = 80
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 20
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier") as? UITableViewCell

if cell == nil {
  cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
} else {
  cell?.contentView.subviews.map {
    currentSubview in
    (currentSubview as UIView).removeFromSuperview()
  }

  if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
    let otherTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, 150, 30))
    otherTitle.text = "My Title testing"
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(otherTitle)

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(170, 30, 100, 40))
    button.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(button)
  } else if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 {

    let boxView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, 130, 30))
    boxView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(boxView)

    let otherButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(140, 50, 70, 30))
    otherButton.backgroundColor = .brownColor()
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(otherButton)

  } else {
    let otherTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, 150, 30))
    otherTitle.text = "OTHER TITLE TESTING"
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(otherTitle)
  }
}

println(cell?.subviews.count)

cell?.textLabel?.text = "TESTING"

return cell!
  }
}
```

I don't know if this code can help you in getting things to work. I suggest you to create a UITableViewCell subclass for more complex view related stuffs, like this one. This class could have some helper methods(addViews and removeViews for example) and include some layout position code to be performed in the layoutSubviews method (this methods is called when a cell is reused). Also, would be helpful to position your views using AL, and setting a flag to make sure the constraints are added just once. About your last question, it's not a good idea to perform UI related stuffs in the background, behavior can be hard to debug and unexpected. When using GCD with related UI stuffs, we have to be careful.